# Lookup with where clause ssrs?

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have a question about a look up function in ssrs. After some research on the forum I managed it to a certain degree. However the last step I can't solve.

In my report I am using two data sets. One set with some costumer parameters and one data set with the turnover grouped by (tip out of this forum) costumer ID and year. With this costumer ID I link the two tables.

```
=lookup(Fields!cmp_wwn.Value,Fields!cmp_wwn.Value, Fields!Omzet.Value,  "Omzet")
```

When I use the code above I get the first value out of the set. However I want to specify which year I want to show.

With the code below I have tried it again.

```
=lookup(
Fields!cmp_wwn.Value & "-" & "2015",
Fields!cmp_wwn.Value & "-" & Fields!Datumjaar.Value,
Fields!Omzet.Value,  "Omzet")
```

The warning below appears. 
Warning 1   [rsRuntimeErrorInExpression] The Value expression for the textrun ‘Textbox8.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ contains an error: Operator '&' is not defined for type 'Guid' and string "-".

Just to give you an idea of the two data sets:
Dataset 1:

```
    SELECT        Status, StartDate, Jaar, 
Maand, Week, cmp_name, Accountmanager, Classificatie, cmp_fcity, Description, RequestComments, fullname, res_id, cmp_code, target, 
                         cmp_wwn
FROM            _VW_ALKLIMAET_MRS_Bezoekverslagen
```

Dataset 2:

```
SELECT        SUM(bdr_val) AS Omzet, Datumjaar, cmp_wwn
FROM            _VW_ALKLIMAET_MRS_omzet
WHERE        (Datumjaar > 2013)
GROUP BY Datumjaar, cmp_wwn
```

---

**Sample data of Dataset 1:**
Status  Start date  Year    Month   Week    Relation name   Account manager Realtion classification City    fullname    ID fullname Costumer code   Target  Relation ID
Status  Startdate   Jaar    Maand   Week    cmp_name    Accountmanager  Classificatie   cmp_fcity   fullname    res_id  cmp_code    target  cmp_wwn
3   12-8-2014 8:00  2014    8   33  van Dorp Hengelo    Martijn Moekotte    Unknown HENGELO Martijn Moekotte                                                    849             2010935 0   4a3a0504-c255-4e91-b106-0000972bb783
3   4-6-2013 13:30  2013    6   23  Witte Koeltechniek BV   Marco van der Haven B Installateur  NOORD-SCHARWOUDE    Marco van der Haven                                                 815              200183 0   cfa97188-c76a-457c-ba78-003d499d86bc
3   6-11-2013 10:00 2013    11  45  Witte Koeltechniek BV   Marco van der Haven B Installateur  NOORD-SCHARWOUDE    Marco van der Haven                                                 815              200183 0   cfa97188-c76a-457c-ba78-003d499d86bc

**Sample data of Dataset 2:**

- Turnover DataYear    Relation ID Omzet      Datumjaar    cmp_wwn
  -36755,5 2015    f887da07-08ad-4479-84ec-1459be5e3311
  -105     2016    ba9e2640-291f-43ee-af5b-559245af165c
  -6409        2014    c06cb96c-026a-4274-9db2-89cf9c8ccb2b
  -176     2014    70968c94-b3b9-43a0-8b2b-18e62583c75f

Comment: The error you are getting is caused by a GUID data type which implicitly  cannot be converted to string. What column is declared as GUID data type?

Comment: I have checked it but no guid is found. One remark is that only using this new statment it gives this fault. With 'my old' statement it does not give this fault. Has it something to do with the &?

Comment: Try using the expression in my update.

Comment: I have checked it but it gives the same result. In the code the field!datumjaar.value is red underlined. So I think the warning has to do with this field. If I check in SQL this is not I Guid or a String field. Can I check more?

Comment: Share a sample of your data, it is hard to guess the data types you are using even more if the field name is not describing the data in english language.

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate two fields in the lookup function.

```
=lookup(
Fields!cmp_wwn.Value & "-" & "2015",
Fields!cmp_wwn.Value & "-" & Fields!Year.Value,
Fields!Omzet.Value,  "Omzet")
```

It will give you the `Omzet` value for the customer your row contains and 2015 year. If you want to simplify the expression you can add a calculated field in every dataset and set an expression to concatenate `cmp_wwn` and `year`.

```
=Fields!cmp_wwn.Value & "-" & Fields!Year.Value
```

Now in your lookup just use the calculated field.

```
=lookup(
Fields!calculated_field.Value,
Fields!calculated_field.Value,
Fields!Omzet.Value,  "Omzet")
```

**UPDATE:** GUID field doesn't support `&` operator

```
=lookup(
CSTR(Fields!cmp_wwn.Value) & "-" & "2015",
CSTR(Fields!cmp_wwn.Value) & "-" & CSTR(Fields!Datumjaar.Value),
Fields!Omzet.Value,  "Omzet")
```

Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: I just put your code in to my report. Unfortunatly it gives just an error in the preview.

=lookup(
Fields!cmp_wwn.Value & "-" & "2015",
Fields!cmp_wwn.Value & "-" & Fields!Datumjaar.Value,
Fields!Omzet.Value,  "Omzet")

Comment: @Erwin, What error are you getting? If you edit your question to include sample data and a better description of the results you are expecting, it would help.